# Vim is unable to find Python

Tags: linux, vimscript-python

I'm using Vim on Fedora 28 and Python seems to be enabled:

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul 11 2018 10:00:51)
Included patches: 1-177
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               +perl/dyn          +vartabs
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       +lua/dyn           +ruby/dyn          +writebackup
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xim
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
```

Hovewer, when I open Vim and issue `:echo has('python')` it returns 0

Both Python 2.x and 3.x version are installed on Fedora by default.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does `has ('python3')` says ? (I ask because `has ('python')` and `has ('python3')` cannot be true simultaneously)

Comment: Hi, Luc. Thanks for your answer. has ('python3') returns 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `:help python3` and the subsequent sections on `python-2-and-3` and `pythonx`. If python is compiled with `+python/dyn, +python3/dyn`, then it effectively has support for Python 2 and 3.

### Checking available version.

> You can test what Python version is available with:
>
> ```
>    if has('python')
>     echo 'there is Python 2.x'
>    endif
>    if has('python3')
>      echo 'there is Python 3.x'
>    endif
> ```

### Checking the version which was compiled with Vim without loading Python

> Note however, that when Python 2 and 3 are both available and loaded
>   dynamically, these has() calls will try to load them.  If only one can be
>   loaded at a time, just checking if Python 2 or 3 are available will prevent
>   the other one from being available.
>
> To avoid loading the dynamic library, only check if Vim was compiled with
>   python support:
>
> ```
>  if has('python_compiled')
>    echo 'compiled with Python 2.x support'
>    if has('python_dynamic')
>      echo 'Python 2.x dynamically loaded'
>    endif
>  endif
>  if has('python3_compiled')
>    echo 'compiled with Python 3.x support'
>    if has('python3_dynamic')
>      echo 'Python 3.x dynamically loaded'
>    endif
>  endif
> ```

### Using pyx

Using `pyx` in the place of `python2` or `python3` will automatically select the version set by `pyxversion`.
This also provides another way to check the version.

> To see what version of Python is being used:
>
> ```
>  :pyx import sys
>  :pyx print(sys.version)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

because of vim installed as 32-bit, but python installation using x64.
uninstall the python x64 and re-install python ( default is 32bit ) will fix the issue.